# Why in Angularjs on selecting one checkbox, all checbox getting selected?

Tags: angularjs

Hey guyz i am having issue related to checkboxes in html, i am using angularjs.
Whenever i checked one checkbox other checkbox getting selected and vice-versa.
Here's my Html code.

```
<form ng-show='MyForm'>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<div name="sampleName"  ng-repeat="sample in list" >
 <input ng-model="q.sample" type="checkbox" >{{sample.name}}</label>
</div>
</div>
 <button ng-click="submitForm()" >Submit</button>
 <button ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

But instead of using scope variable name 'q.sample', if i use only $scope.sample then it is working fine. 
Still there is another issue with this too, On submitting data my form gets closed, but when i open it again, it shows me fresh form, there is no checked field, but if i cancel the form instead of submitting it with checked values and again opened it , i dont want the checked values to be present but i am getting the checked values instead of fresh form.
I tried to make values false in checkbox field on cancel button . See my Code of cancelForm()

```
$scope.cancelForm = function() {
    $scope.MyForm = false
    $scope.q.sample = false
}
```

So Basically, i have two questions, one is why i am getting all checkboxes selected on selected only one checkbox when i am using

```
$scope.q.sample
```

Second when i am using only

```
$scope.sample
```

scope value of sample is not reflecting on UI though it is reflecting in JS, i am getting the checked checkboxes.

Comment: Hi! Please actually paste your HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are binding `ng-model` to the same controller property with this:

```
ng-model="q.sample"
```

Instead, if you want to select each individually then you need to have a different `ng-model` for each checkbox.

At the moment, you are changing `q.sample` and this, then, binds the value of `q.sample` to all the other checkboxes that define `ng-model="q.sample"`.

Try something like this instead:

```
<div name="sampleName"  ng-repeat="item in list" >
    <input ng-model="item.checked" type="checkbox" >{{sample.name}}</label>
</div>
```

and then in `cancelForm()`:

```
$scope.cancelForm = function() {
    $scope.MyForm = false

    angular.forEach($scope.list, function(item) {
        item.checked = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Davin , How to have different ng-model for each checkbox, cause i am using ng-repeat on checbox.

Comment: I showed an example of how to do this.  You can use the repeated `sample` and then use a property on each one.  In my example it is the `sample.checked` property.  I'll make it more clear by not using the word `sample`.

Comment: Ok, I renamed `sample` to `item`, but it makes no difference.  Angular will create a scoped property `item.checked` for each `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Hi Davin , Can you please explain this code to me.  angular.forEach($scope.list, function(item) {
        item.checked = false;
});

Comment: I got it , Thanks Davin

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as David Tryon mentioned, you are assigning the same ng-model to all the checkboxes and what you want is a different ng-model for each checkbox.

You can solve this by assigning a javascript expression to ng-model

for example:

```
ng-model="list[$index].checked"
```